# Is there any force that affect to wearable accelerometer underwater?

Tags: forces, acceleration, water

I am trying to find displacement of underwater sport player with my accelerometer sensor. My question is; is there any force that affect to an object that weared by a human underwater? Thanks.

Comment: Why tag with particle-accelerators???

Comment: @JonCuster as I know Everything is made up of particles

Comment: But that isn’t what that tag means at all.

Comment: @JonCuster yes, let me remove the tag